# Adding addEventListener to a clicked table cell to change the color

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am creating a dynamic table of three columns and multiple rows. I want to be able to click the last cells in each row and have the row be selected showing a certain color. I am trying to do this as well as make sure that if another cell is selected already it will deselect.  I am having a few issues not sure exactly what to do. I can create an onclick alert message that works, however no success with the bg color.  Any suggestions are helpful. Function createCell should be where this is addressed.

```
<html>
<br/><br/></p>
<table id="my_table" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Age</td>
<td>Sex</td>
</tr>

 </table>
<p></center></p>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

 function appendRow(){


var names = ["Paul", "Mike", "Linda"];
var ages = ["16", "23", "44"];
var male_female = ["M", "M", "F"];
var tbl = document.getElementById('my_table'); // table reference
// append table row
var id;
var z=1;
for(k=0;k<names.length;k++){    
var row = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length);


    var j = tbl.rows.length - 2;
    for (var i=0;i<tbl.rows[0].cells.length;i++) {
        id=z++;
          var cell_text = '';
          if (i == 0) {
                 cell_text = names[j];
          } else if (i == 1) {
                 cell_text = ages[j];
          } else if (i == 2) {
                 cell_text = male_female[j];
          }
        createCell(id, row.insertCell(i), cell_text, 'row');

    }


  }


}

function createCell(id, cell, text, style){

var div = document.createElement('div'); // create DIV element

var txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
if(id % 3 == 0)
{
          cell.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("hello")');    //for testing purposes
      cell.addEventListener("click", clickCell, false);
}
div.appendChild(txt);                    // append text node to the DIV
div.setAttribute('class', style);        // set DIV class attribute
div.setAttribute('className', style);    // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
cell.appendChild(div);            // append DIV to the table cell
}

  function clickCell()
 {
if(e)
  e.setAttribute("bgColor","purple");

 if(e != this){
    e = this;
    e.setAttribute("bgColor","blue");
 }else{
   e = null;
  }
 }      





 </script>
<BODY onload="appendRow()">

<style>
table#my_table{border-collapse:collapse;}
 table#my_table td{width:50px;height:27px;border:1px solid #D3D3D3;font-size:10pt;text-align:center;padding:0;}
  .append_row{background-color:#FFD6D6;border:1px #ccc solid;}
 </style>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What is `e` in `clickCell`? I cannot find it declared anywhere. `this` in the function will refer to the `window` element. `addEventListener` does not exist in IE btw (afaik).

Comment: Truth is I dont know exactly what I am doing. Couldn't find any reference to this kind of a call so I just threw some stuff in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the `clickCell` method to:

```
function clickCell(e) {
    // clear the background of all rows
    var rows = document.getElementById('my_table').rows;
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
    // set background of clicked row
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
}
```

See an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nj4fj/).

Comment: How do you change the background color on only the clicked cell? Thanks for the help

Comment: `this` refers to the `<td>` element in this function. Don't call `this.parentNode` which will get the `<tr>` element, and simply do `this.style.backgroundColor = 'purple'`. Updated answer.

Comment: I see that if you set this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'purple'; to this.style.....it does only change the cell's background color. thanks again

Comment: As far as removing the background color from the cell how do you manage that? I've tried just about everything I can think of. Tried using a loop like I did to populate the elements of the table.

Comment: See the linked example. It removes the background color of all rows.

Comment: Hmm...Is it browser specific? If I run the example in FF, and add the changes I can click a cell, and change the color. If I click another cell it changes the color leaving the other one still colored. And so on until all three are colored. If I run this in IE I get some object error and it doesn't even print the table. Not to worried about the IE error, I guess addEventListener is FF only, not sure..its not working for me. ha ha

Answer (score 3):

In createCell change `cell.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("hello")');` to `cell.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("hello");this.parentNode.setAttribute("bgcolor", "purple")');`

Comment: That does work, however, it changes the color of the 3rd row to purple. I only want the clicked cell to change color.  This.parentNode.parentNode.setAttritube will color the entire table.

Comment: then use this.setAttribute and also i used only this.parentNode thinking you wanted to change color of entire row. this refers to currentcell since that is the element on which the onclick event is registered

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that if I set the clickcell function to the following, it will clear all cells that are colored. I thought I could call "this.style.backgroundColor" to change the cell color and then clear that cell with a "row.style.backgroundColor" turns out I was wrong.

```
function clickCell(e) {
var tr = document.getElementById('my_table').rows;

for(i=0;i<tr.length;i++)
{
    for(k=0;k<tr[i].cells.length;k++)
    {
        tr[i].cells[k].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
}   
this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```